XSLT mapping to correct XML format in Input file
I am checking on the possibility of correcting the input XML file syntax with XSLT 1.0 mapping, but not able to find any relevant blogs, is this even possible ?
Input is a combination multiple files,  below are the sample input and outputs, Please suggest.
Input
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HEADER>
    <CHILD BEGIN="1">
        <RECORD SEGMENT="1">
            <FIELD1>value1</FIELD1>
            <FIELD2>2</FIELD2>      
        </RECORD>       
    </CHILD>
</HEADER>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HEADER>
    <CHILD BEGIN="1">
        <RECORD SEGMENT="1">
            <FIELD1>value2</FIELD1>
            <FIELD2>3</FIELD2>

        </RECORD>   
    </CHILD>
</HEADER>

output
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HEADER>
    <CHILD BEGIN="1">
        <RECORD SEGMENT="1">
            <FIELD1>value1</FIELD1>
            <FIELD2>2</FIELD2>      
        </RECORD>       
    </CHILD>

    <CHILD BEGIN="1">
        <RECORD SEGMENT="1">
            <FIELD1>value2</FIELD1>
            <FIELD2>3</FIELD2>

        </RECORD>   
    </CHILD>
</HEADER>



In XSLT 2/3, as pointed in a comment to the other answer, you could try to process the input as plain text (by using unparsed-text on the input file or by passing its content as a string value/string item to the transformation):
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]" name="xsl:initial-template">
    
    <xsl:variable name="elements" as="element()*">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="tokenize(., '\r?\n')" group-starting-with=".[starts-with(., '&lt;?xml version')]">
        <xsl:sequence select="(current-group() => tail() => string-join('&#10;') => parse-xml-fragment()) ! *"/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>      
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each-group select="$elements" group-by="node-name()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*, current-group()!*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Online example passing input as string value/string item.

The input you show is not a well-formed XML document (no single root element, repeated XML declaration) and cannot be processed by XSLT.

Well, not directly, anyway. But a solution that works in nearly all cases would be to read the file using unparsed-text(), split it into multiple documents using regular expressions, then process these individual documents using parse-xml(). That requires XSLT 3.0. If you're determined to use 1.0 you could do the preprocessing using some other language. Either way, you need to accept that the solution won't be 100% perfect, for example handling a "commented out" XML declaration correctly will be difficult.
